# C# Loop method every minute, it file exist do something, if not wait untill its created

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a program that will check if .csv file is created. If created, do something, if not wait untill its created. Is it possible in C#?

Tried something like this but didn't work well...

```
        var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
        var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            if (!File.Exists(@"TestFileLocation"))
        {
            MethodName(); //Tried this to start method agian
        }
        else
        {
            HereIsRestOfTheCodeToDoSomeActions();
        }
        }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

If my post isn't clear enough, sorry I'm not fluent in English, below are steps, how program will work:

1. Check if file is created in folder
2. If not, wait 1 minute and check again
3. If file is created do some things
4. Loop this steps from start

Comment: There's no need for loops, set the Timer to elapse / tick each minute. You have to decide whether the Timer stops when the file is found or it keeps on running -- Anyway, take a look at the [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) class: this sends notification events when a File is created in the Folder / Subfolders you're *watching*.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher amen. Avoid using System Threading Timers Timer in winforms; use a System Windows Forms Timer instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perfect fit for your problem would be to use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0). Its job is to watch a directory for changes such as the creation of files as you need it in your problem.

That would also make the one-minute-threshold obsolete. Consider for example:

```
// necessary assembly using for using FileSystemWatcher classes.
using System.IO;

// ...

// instantiate your watcher.
using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\path\to\folder");

// just filter for interesting attribtes.
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;

// attach an event handler to the event that is triggered when a file is created.
watcher.Created += OnCreated;

// ...

// implement the event handler.
private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // if the name is "your" name, you're ready to go ...
    if (e.Name == "my_name")
        // do something ...

}
```

However, if you still want to use a loop (due to constraints you didn't state in your post), then it might probably be something like the following *less adorable* approach:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var waitTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    
while (true)
{
    if (!File.Exists(@"TestFileLocation"))
    {
        // do something ...
            
        // exit the loop.
        break;
    }
        
    Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
}
```

**Note and take care** that this endless-loop blocks the main thread until you found your file. A better approach would be to execute that task in a separate thread aside from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Create FileSystemWatcher https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0 and add check in OnCreated

Comment: That's more of a comment really; go the extra mile and show them how to apply it in their situation

Answer (score 0):

This code is in short the same as @markwellman other than wrapping code into a class. The code does not wait, it keeps monitoring and with that see no reason why to stop and start.

In the following example, pass the folder to watch and file file name to watch in the constructor of `FileOperations`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using static System.IO.Path;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class FileOperations : FileSystemWatcher
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Path to check for file
        /// </summary>
        public string MonitorPath { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// File name to watch for
        /// </summary>
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        
        public FileOperations(string monitorPath, string fileName)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(monitorPath))
            {
                throw new Exception($"Missing {monitorPath}");
            }

            MonitorPath = monitorPath;

            Created += OnCreated;

            Path = MonitorPath;
            Filter = fileName;
            FileName = fileName;
            EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
        }

        private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            var fileName = Combine(MonitorPath, GetFileName(e.FullPath));
            
            if (fileName.Equals(Combine(MonitorPath,FileName), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // TODO
            }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in a form create a private instance of `FileOperations`. Invoke Stop method in form Closing event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly FileOperations _fileOperations =
        new FileOperations("Path to watch", "file name to trigger on");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Closing += OnClosing;
    }

    private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        _fileOperations.Stop();
    }
}
```